# How to add max-length attribute to Angular-xeditable?

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-xeditable

```html
<span editable-text="contact.phoneNumber" maxlength="5"  e-name="phoneNumber" e-form="contactForm" >
  {{ contact.phoneNumber || '' }}
</span>
```

I have used the directive inside a span and it is generating and inputbox on run time, when we click on a button to edit the Contact  Number. I want to add a maximum length to this input box. Any suggestions?

Comment: use limit: value, here value is the max length you want to provide. See this for help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: What this will do is take a large number of input but display only within the limit. I need to take the input only in limited quantity. Its like entering your phone number and knowing that the constraint is for 10 digits only.

Comment: Would you like to use regexp

Comment: Err.., it is more about limiting the input entries rather than validating them using regexp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use

```
e-maxlength e-minlength
```

if you see the [documentacion](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#ref-element) , on e attribute you have this:

> Attributes defined with e-* prefix automatically transfered from original element to control.

Comment: what if you want it dynamic? like for credit cards, limit VISA to 16, but AMEX to 15

Answer (score 0):

Create  a directive to limit the value:

```
app.directive("limitTo", [function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
        angular.element(elem).on("keydown", function() {
            if (this.value.length == limit) return false;
        });
    }
}   }]);

<input limit-to="4" type="number" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="search.main" placeholder="enter first 4 digits: 09XX">
```

Hope this will be helping you